# Oracle get values from :new, :old dynamically by string key

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to get a value from special `:new` or `:old` by "string key"?

e.g. in PHP:

```
$key = 'bar';
$foo[$key]; //get foo value
```

How to in Oracle?

```
:new.bar --get :new 'bar' value
```

and

```
key = 'bar';
:new[key] --How to?
```

Is it possible?
Thx!

Comment: By string key you mean the name of the column?

Comment: you want a trigger to return an assoc array?

Comment: @tbone I think the OP wants to use `:new` and `:old` as assoc arrays, with the column names...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

> A trigger that fires at row level can access the data in the row that
>   it is processing by using correlation names. The default correlation
>   names are OLD, NEW, and PARENT.
>
> ...
>
> OLD, NEW, and PARENT are also
>   called pseudorecords, because they have record structure, but are
>   allowed in fewer contexts than records are. The structure of a
>   pseudorecord is table_name%ROWTYPE, where table_name is the name of
>   the table on which the trigger is created (for OLD and NEW) or the
>   name of the parent table (for PARENT).

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#autoId4

So, these correlation names are basically records. Record is not a key-value storage so you cannot reference its by string key.

Here's what you can do with them:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/composites.htm#CIHFCFCJ

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/trigger/new_old.html)

The first approach is syntactically good, it is to to be used like this:

```
create trigger trg_before_insert before insert on trigger_tbl
  for each row
begin
  insert into trigger_log (txt) values ('[I] :old.a=' || :old.a || ', :new.a='||:new.a);
end;
/
```

But if you want to access the field dynamically, one ugly thing that I can think of, that seems to be working (which is not dynamic in the end at all...): using a CASE WHEN... statement for each column you want to be able to use dynamically...

Something along these lines (updating the :new record):

```
key='bar';
value = 'newValue';
CASE key
    WHEN 'bar' THEN :new.bar = value;
    WHEN 'foo' THEN :new.foo = value;
    WHEN 'baz' THEN :new.baz = value;
END;
```

To read a value from "dynamic column":

```
key='bar';
value =  CASE key
        WHEN 'bar' THEN :new.bar;
        WHEN 'foo' THEN :new.foo;
        WHEN 'baz' THEN :new.baz;
    END;
```

Then use the value variable as required...

**Beware** however, as @beherenow noted:

> - what's the datatype of `value` variable in your reading example?
> - and how can you be sure you're not going to encounter a type mismatch?

These are questions that require decisions from the implementing side. For example, with a squint, this thing could be used to dynamically use values from columns that share the same type.

I have to emphasize though, that I don't see a situation where such a bizarre contraption I proposed is to be used, nor do I support using this. The reason I kept it here, after @beherenow's complete and definitive answer is so that everyone finding this page can see - though there might be a way, it shouldn't be used...

To me, this thing seems:

- ugly
- brittle
- badly scaling
- appalling
- difficult to maintain
- ...aaand horribly ugly...

I definitely recommend rethinking the use case you need this for. I myself would angrily shout with someone writing this kind of code, unless this is absolutely the only way, and the whole universe collapses, if this is not done this way... (This is very much unlikely though)

<sub>Sorry if I misunderstood your question, it was not totally clear to me</sub>

Comment: you're assuming OP tries to write :new record, but I bet he tries to read it

Comment: @beherenow I don't know, as this is something that _can_ be done, but never ever _should_ be done... But for the sake of completeness (or to make things worse?), I included that use case too...

Comment: what's the datatype of `value` variable in your reading example? and how can you be sure you're not going to encounter a type mismatch?

Comment: Your questions are totally valid... But not knowing what's behind the story - I'd say, this is the responsibility of the one trying to use this... As is the responsibility of actually using such a struct. However, I add these concerns to this answer, as you are right, these are important.